# Scale number of pods in OpenShift from oc command line

Tags: openshift

I am new to Openshift , and want know how to change the number of pods of  specific deployment from `oc` command line.

I tried to do:

oc scale dc name_of_deployment--replicas=2

Error from server (NotFound): deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io "name_of_deployment" not found

My deployments were installed with helm, if i do

```
oc  get dc
```

I am getting some other deployment but not the one that I want to scale.

Note: The deployment that I want to delete is running without any issue.

Answer (score 4):

found the issue,  instead of 'dc' need to use 'deploy'

```
oc scale deploy name_of_deployment--replicas=2
```

Comment: i made a [tutorial](https://github.com/ocd-scm/ocd-meta/wiki/Short-Tutorial:-Git-Driven-Deployments-On-Minishift) that showed scaling up by pushing config into git to have it update a deployment. here is a [video of how that works](https://www.loom.com/share/a321695dcf2146efa4599cae358d3a4c).